# Google Slides API deleteObject() when object not exists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I want to update an existing object/image in a Google Slide. This works as long as the object exists:

```
var requests = [
    {
      "deleteObject": {
        "objectId": 'image01'
      }
    },
    {
      "createImage": {
        "url": imageUrl,
        "objectId": 'image01',
        "elementProperties": {
          "pageObjectId": pageId,
          "size": {
            "width": {
              "magnitude": 250,
              "unit": "PT"
            },
            "height": {
              "magnitude": 250,
              "unit": "PT"
            }
          },
          "transform": {
            "scaleX": 1,
            "scaleY": 1,
            "translateX": 200,
            "translateY": 100,
            "unit": "PT"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ];
  var response = Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, presentationId);
```

However, if a user previously deleted the object in the presentation, it is not re-created.

The following error message appear:

> Invalid requests[0].deleteObject: The object (image01) could not be
>   found.

How can I query whether an object exists in presentation?

Comment: Why does the error refer to the object as MyImage_01 when there is no mention of that string in the var requests?  Are you using the wrong name perhaps?

Comment: Thank you. That was my fault. The error message with MyImage_01 was from another function. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about retrieving a object list using slides.presentations.get? In order to confirm whether objects exist, it uses `slides/pageElements/objectId` for fields of slides.presentations.get. You can know the exist of objects using the object list.

### Sample script :

```
var response = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId);
response.slides.forEach(function(e1, i1){
  e1.pageElements.forEach(function(e2){
    Logger.log("Page %s, objectId %s", i1 + 1, e2.objectId);
  });
});
```

### Result :

```
Page 1.0, objectId ###
Page 2.0, objectId ###
Page 3.0, objectId ###
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

If you want to search a value from whole JSON, you can use following simple script. When `value2` is included in `sampledata`, `~JSON.stringify(sampledata).indexOf('value2')` becomes true. In this sample, `ok` is shown, because value2 is included in sampledata.

**But it's a bit of a stretch. If you can know the complete structure of JSON, I think that the compare of value using key is better.**

```
var sampledata = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};
if (~JSON.stringify(sampledata).indexOf('value2')) { 
  Logger.log("ok")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was useful. The variable 'response' contains all information I need. How can I search for the string 'image01' in the variable? response.indexOf('image01'); does not work

Comment: @Roberto B What is the string 'image01'? ``objectId`` is the string like ``g1234567890_0_0``. If you had modified the objectId to 'image01', you can use it. But I don't know how to modify the objectId. If you want to update the object, after it retrieved objectId, you can update it using objectId. I worry about I may misunderstand your comment. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The variable 'response' contains the string 'image01'. I found it with Logger.log. Now I have to query it. If the string exists, it should output the value true. If not, then the value is false. In an array I find it with indexOf. But how can I find a string in the variable 'response'? Or should I fill an extra array in your function? f.e. var response = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId);
response.slides.forEach(function(e1, i1){
  e1.pageElements.forEach(function(e2){
    Logger.log("Page %s, objectId %s", i1 + 1, e2.objectId);
    array.push(objectId);
  });
});

Comment: @Roberto B I have 2 questions for your comment. 1. Can you show us the result included 'image01' in the response? In my environment, my Logger.log() is not included 'image01'. If I could know it, I might be able to propose a sample script. 2. Can you show us about the method to create the object with objectId of 'image01'? If I could create the same scenes, I can think of the solution. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: content of response: `......EFT}}}, transform={scaleX=217.7858, scaleY=217.7858, unit=EMU, translateY=1363157.895, translateX=2000000}, size={width={unit=EMU, magnitude=27550}, height={unit=EMU, magnitude=15950}}, **objectId=image01**}], pageProperties={pageBackgroundFill={propertyState=INHERIT}}, slideProperties={notesPage={pageElements=[{transform={scaleX=2.032, scaleY=1.143, unit=EMU, translateY=685800, translateX=381300}, shape={shapePropertie........`

Comment: creating the object: var imageId = 'image01'; `createImage: {
    objectId: imageId,
    url: imageUrl,
    elementProperties: {
      pageObjectId: pageId,
      size: {
        height: emu4M,
        width: emu4M
      },
      transform: {
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        translateX: 2000000,
        translateY: 100000,
        unit: 'EMU'
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: @Roberto B Using the key which has ``image01**``, you can compare whether "image01" is included in the value using a script like ``if (~value.indexOf('image01')) { do something }``. Although I cannot retrieve the complete key from a part of JSON data you showed, you who has the complete JSON can do it. And about creating the object, I didn't know what you did using that. I'm sorry.

Comment: This is my problem. I can't search in the variable 'response'. If I use `if (response.indexOf('image01')) { Logger.log('hello world'); }` the error message appears `TypeError: Funktion indexOf in Objekt {"slides":[{"pageElements":[{"transform":`

Comment: @Roberto B OK. I could understand your problem. I can prepare a sample script for searching value. Please wait a moment.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @Roberto B Thank you, too. But I'm sorry for being late.